# JPA + Hibernate + CrudRepository flush?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to flush my data, for this I have the following method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional
public String musicSubmit(@ModelAttribute Music music, Model model) {
    musicRepository.saveAndFlush(music);
    model.addAttribute("music", music);
    return "result";
}
```

My model

```
public interface MusicRepository extends JpaRepository<Music, Integer> {

}
```

My main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My data are visible but if I shutdown the application and run again, they  disapears even if I set my applications.properties like this

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

How can I keep my data, even if shutdown the application or restart my computer ?

Comment: You didn't include the most important part: what DB are you using?

Comment: None, it's seems that spring boot JPA starter doesn't provide any database :o thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:file:~/some_path/YourVeryDbFile
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.database = H2

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

Notice this uses **H2**; if you want something else (**MYSQL**) you should specify it otherwise (and change the values accordingly).

Have a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).